# HTML5 canvas color get a bit lighter although setting globalCompositeOperation to source-over

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, canvas

I am painting one canvas on another. In some cases both canvases have the same lines (same pixels, same colors). I am setting global composite operation of the context to be source-over.
However, the resulting lines have colors that are a lighter than the original color.
I am not sure why.I am using GWT if it is of any difference

Comment: Could you post your code you use?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't - it is a very complex code

Comment: "very complex code" = "lots of unspoken complexity that may be causing the problem".  Try creating a simple test case to reproduce the problem.  Odds are you'll figure out the issue.  Worst case, you have simple code you can post here.